# Access camera when app is minimized

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-service

In my application I access the camera by retrieving the camera object. Then I start a service that continously manages some data. In certain cases the service sends a broadcast request to the activity to use the camera object.

So when my app get's minimized the service cannot use the camera anymore. Why? When I go back to my app it crashes

> 02-15 18:06:56.100: E/AndroidRuntime(23686): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-15 18:06:56.100: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10 (has extras) } in
>   com.mkyong.android.MainActivity$1@418e4730

The entire stack trace http://dpaste.com/933015/

So there is an intent `android.intent.action.MAIN` send by the service but never received by the activity.

I catch the intent like this in my activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                "android.intent.action.MAIN");

        mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               //access camera
            }
        };

        this.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
```

So is there a chance to catch the intent and access camera when the app is minimized? How can I do that?

Comment: Please paste the *entire* stack trace, including all stanzas, not just the first line.

Comment: Here it is http://dpaste.com/933015/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your stack trace indicates, you have called `release()` on the `Camera`, after which point the `Camera` object is no longer valid. You cannot call `getParameters()` on a `Camera` after `release()`.

Comment: Well, I remove the release (it was in onPause method), now when I return to the app I don't get the exception. However while the app is minimized the camera cannot be accessed

Comment: actually, I want to turn on flashlight, but it is not turned on, while when I get back to the app it is turned on

Comment: You might consider asking a separate StackOverflow question specifically about what you are trying to accomplish ("turn on flashlight" "while the app is minimized").

Comment: Ok, I did so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901236/turn-on-flashlight-while-app-is-minimized